# Variable ++ not working

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so I have this game and I want the high score to be updated, but whenever I set my currentScore value of ++, it doesn't increment.  I don't know what is happening, and I am sure it is an easy fix, if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.  The problem is on line 212. I am truly trying to fix this, and I would like to be able to have a quick and easy fix to implement, so that I can go back to designing my website.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body onload ="checkScore">
          <script>
              
          </script>
            <p><span style="color:red">Your</span> <span style="color:orange">current</span> <span style="color:gold">High</span> <span style="color:green">Score</span> <span style="color:blue">is:</span>
            <span id="SCORES" style="color:purple">0</span>
            <input id="currentScore" value="0"> 
   <script>
    var cookie;

              function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
                  var d = new Date();
                  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*365*7*24*60*60*1000));
                  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
                  cookie = encodeURI(cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/");
              }

              function getCookie(cname) {
                  var name = cname + "=";
                  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(cookie);
                  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
                  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                      var c = ca[i];
                      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                          c = c.substring(1);
                      }
                      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                          return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                      }
                  }
                  return "";
              }

              function checkScore() {
                // get current score
                let currentScore = document.getElementById('currentScore').value;

                //get high score from the "cookie"
                let highScore = getCookie('highscore');

                // if current score is bigger then high score - set new high score and update cookie
                if (highScore < currentScore) {
                  highScore = currentScore;
                  setCookie("highscore", highScore, 365);
                }

                // update DOM
                document.getElementById("SCORES").innerHTML = highScore;
              }

              // set inital cookie for this example to work
              setCookie("highscore", 0, 365);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
   var
   COLS = 26,
   ROWS = 26,
   EMPTY = 0,
   SNAKE = 1,
   FRUIT = 2,
   LEFT  = 0,
   UP    = 1,
   RIGHT = 2,
   DOWN  = 3,
   KEY_LEFT  = 65,
   KEY_UP    = 87,
   KEY_RIGHT = 68,
   KEY_DOWN  = 83,

   canvas,
   ctx,
   keystate,
   frames,
   score;
    currentScore;
   grid = {
    width: null,
    height: null,
    _grid: null,
    init: function(d, c, r) {
     this.width = c;
     this.height = r;
     this._grid = [];
     for (var x=0; x < c; x++) {
      this._grid.push([]);
      for (var y=0; y < r; y++) {
       this._grid[x].push(d);
      }
     }
    },
    set: function(val, x, y) {
     this._grid[x][y] = val;
    },
    get: function(x, y) {
     return this._grid[x][y];
    }
   }
   snake = {
    direction: null,
    last: null,
    _queue: null,
    init: function(d, x, y) {
     this.direction = d;
     this._queue = [];
     this.insert(x, y);
    },
    insert: function(x, y) {
     this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y});
     this.last = this._queue[0];
    },
    remove: function() {
     return this._queue.pop();
    }
   };
   function setFood() {
    var empty = [];
    for (var x=0; x < grid.width; x++) {
     for (var y=0; y < grid.height; y++) {
      if (grid.get(x, y) === EMPTY) {
       empty.push({x:x, y:y});
      }
     }
    }
    var randpos = empty[Math.round(Math.random()*(empty.length - 1))];
    grid.set(FRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);
   }
   function main() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = COLS*20;
    canvas.height = ROWS*20;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    ctx.font = "18px Helvetica";
    frames = 0;
    keystate = {};
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
     keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
     delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
    });
    init();
    loop();
   }
   function init() {
    score = 0;
        currentScore = 0;
    grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);
    var sp = {x:Math.floor(COLS/2), y:ROWS-1};
    snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y);
    grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);
    setFood();
   }
   function loop() {
    update();
    draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
   }
   function update() {
    frames++;
    if (keystate[KEY_LEFT] && snake.direction !== RIGHT) {
     snake.direction = LEFT;
    }
    if (keystate[KEY_UP] && snake.direction !== DOWN) {
     snake.direction = UP;
    }
    if (keystate[KEY_RIGHT] && snake.direction !== LEFT) {
     snake.direction = RIGHT;
    }
    if (keystate[KEY_DOWN] && snake.direction !== UP) {
     snake.direction = DOWN;
    }
    if (frames%5 === 0) {
     var nx = snake.last.x;
     var ny = snake.last.y;
     switch (snake.direction) {
      case LEFT:
       nx--;
       break;
      case UP:
       ny--;
       break;
      case RIGHT:
       nx++;
       break;
      case DOWN:
       ny++;
       break;
     }
     if (0 > nx || nx > grid.width-1  ||
      0 > ny || ny > grid.height-1 ||
      grid.get(nx, ny) === SNAKE
     ) {
      return init();
     }
     if (grid.get(nx, ny) === FRUIT) {
      score++;
          currentScore++;
          checkScore();
      setFood();
     } else {
      var tail = snake.remove();
      grid.set(EMPTY, tail.x, tail.y);
     }
     grid.set(SNAKE, nx, ny);
     snake.insert(nx, ny);
    }
   }
   function draw() {
    var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;
    var th = canvas.height/grid.height;
    for (var x=0; x < grid.width; x++) {
     for (var y=0; y < grid.height; y++) {
      switch (grid.get(x, y)) {
       case EMPTY:
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        break;
       case SNAKE:
        ctx.fillStyle = "#4aa024";
        break;
       case FRUIT:
        ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
        break;
      }
      ctx.fillRect(x*tw, y*th, tw, th);
     }
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "#49c2ff";
    ctx.fillText("SCORE: " + score, 10, canvas.height-10);
   }
   main();
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not really a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger?

Comment: There are no line numbers so....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what line 212 is, and I am not going to count. What I do see though is this:

```
score++;
currentScore++;
checkScore();
```

Where `checkScore()` then resets the value to that from your UI element.

```
let currentScore = document.getElementById('currentScore').value;
```

Comment: Thanks so much Matt, this finally got it working! I have another bug with it being 1 extra, so when my score is 1 it displays 2, but that is an issue for another day.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

you have a global variable frames, problem is [`window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames) is also there. So you can not use `frames` as a variable. Change it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was indeed 
`let currentScore = document.getElementById('currentScore').value = score;`
Thanks again Matt for the help!